# Implementing Sample Abstract Factory Pattern using Smart Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Was trying to implement and example code to smart pointer from [link](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory/cpp/before-after).
Is it a good practice? To go with all unique pointers or should we use shared pointers in this case? How can i improve this ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<memory>

void LOG(std::string strText)
{
    std::cout << strText << std::endl;
}

class Widget {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class WindowsBtn : public Widget
{
public:
    void draw() {
        LOG("Windows Button");
    }
};

class WindowsMenu : public Widget
{
public:
    void draw() {
        LOG("Windows Menu");
    }
};

class LinuxBtn : public Widget
{
public:
    void draw() {
        LOG("Linux Button");
    }
};

class LinuxMenu : public Widget
{
public:
    void draw() {
        LOG("Linux Menu");
    }
};
/*
class WidgetFactory
{
public:
    virtual Widget* CreateButton() = 0;
    virtual Widget* CreateMenu() = 0;
};

class WindowsFactory : public WidgetFactory{
public:
    Widget* CreateButton() {
        return (new WindowsBtn);
    }

    Widget* CreateMenu() {
        return (new WindowsMenu);
    }

};

class LinuxFactory : public WidgetFactory{
public:
    Widget* CreateButton() {
        return (new LinuxBtn);
    }

    Widget* CreateMenu() {
        return (new LinuxMenu);
    }

};

class Client
{
    WidgetFactory * factory;
public:
    Client(WidgetFactory* factory) :factory(factory)
    {}

    void draw(){
        Widget * wd = factory->CreateButton();
        wd->draw();
        display1();
        display2();
    }
    void display1()
    {
        Widget * w[] = {
            factory->CreateButton(),
            factory->CreateMenu()
        };
        w[0]->draw();
        w[1]->draw();
    }
    void display2()
    {
        Widget * w[] = {
            factory->CreateMenu(),
            factory->CreateButton()
        };
        w[0]->draw();
        w[1]->draw();
    }

};
*/
class SmartWidgetFactory
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateButton() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateMenu() = 0;
};

class SmartWindowsFactory : public SmartWidgetFactory {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateButton() {
        return std::make_unique<WindowsBtn>();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateMenu() {
        return  std::make_unique<WindowsMenu>();
    }
};

class SmartLinuxFactory : public SmartWidgetFactory {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateButton() {
        return  std::make_unique<LinuxBtn>();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateMenu() {
        return std::make_unique<LinuxMenu>();
    }
};

class SmartClient
{
    std::unique_ptr<SmartWidgetFactory> factory;
public:
    SmartClient(std::unique_ptr<SmartWidgetFactory> oFactory)
    {
        factory = std::move(oFactory);
    }

    void draw() {
        std::unique_ptr<Widget> wd = factory->CreateButton();
        wd->draw();
        display1();
        display2();
    }
    void display1()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Widget> w[] = {
            factory->CreateButton(),
            factory->CreateMenu()
        };
        w[0]->draw();
        w[1]->draw();
    }
    void display2()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Widget> w[] = {
            factory->CreateMenu(),
            factory->CreateButton()
        };
        w[0]->draw();
        w[1]->draw();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    /*WidgetFactory *factory;
    factory = new LinuxFactory;
    Client *c = new Client(factory);
    c->draw();*/

    std::unique_ptr< SmartWidgetFactory > oFactory = std::make_unique<SmartLinuxFactory>();
    std::unique_ptr<SmartClient> oClient = std::make_unique<SmartClient>( std::move(oFactory) );
    oClient->draw();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just found that the ctor `SmartClient(std::unique_ptr<SmartWidgetFactory> oFactory)`  used value instead of reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the **big bug.**  Your `Widget` class has no virtual destructor! This means that every time you return a `unique_ptr<Widget>`, you're losing the information about what *kind* of widget needs destroying.

[Clang will actually diagnose this mistake for you.](https://godbolt.org/z/cuDgyB) No matter what compiler you use, make sure you turn on warnings via `-Wall -Wextra` (or `-W4` on MSVC).

---

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

This is a non-standard main routine. Maybe I'm a POSIX chauvinist, but at least for posting publicly, I'd think it would be more appropriate to use

```
int main(int, char **)
```

or even better,

```
int main()
```

(since you don't use either of those parameters for anything).

Also notice that I'm using `char**` instead of `char*[]`, because in C and C++, [a function parameter cannot be an array.](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428) It is pointless to deceive yourself and mean to deceive others.

---

```
SmartClient(std::unique_ptr<SmartWidgetFactory> oFactory)
```

This constructor should be marked `explicit`. In fact, *every constructor you ever write* (except for copy constructors and move constructors) should be `explicit`. If you leave off the `explicit`, then you're enabling people to write code like

```
std::unique_ptr<SmartWidgetFactory> pf = ...;
SmartClient sc = std::move(pf);
```

or even

```
SmartClient sc = nullptr;
```

and it'll compile, and they won't realize what they did wrong until runtime. It's better to catch this kind of thing at compile time. Mark all your constructors `explicit`.

---

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateButton()
```

If you intended this function to override the virtual function in the base class, you should have marked it `override`. (It may *still* override the virtual function in the base class, even without `override`, if you spelled everything correctly; but don't bet your workday on it. Mark all overriding functions `override` and catch your bugs at compile time.)

Also, consider whether it makes conceptual sense that "creating a button" is a *non-const* method of the factory. Maybe it does; I tend to think it doesn't. So I would write this as

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> CreateButton() const override
```

---

```
std::unique_ptr<SmartClient> oClient = std::make_unique<SmartClient>( std::move(oFactory) );
```

Why does this need to be heap-allocated?

```
auto oClient = SmartClient(std::move(oFactory));
```

Even if you want to keep using `make_unique` for some reason, consider replacing the cumbersome type name `std::unique_ptr<SmartClient>` with `auto`:

```
auto oClient = std::make_unique<SmartClient>(std::move(oFactory));
```

Notice I've also normalized the whitespace while I'm at it.

---

```
void LOG(std::string strText)
```

Pass large expensive-to-copy objects, such as `std::string`, by const reference.

```
void LOG(const std::string& text)
```

If you are on C++17, consider replacing `const std::string&` parameters with `std::string_view` parameters:

```
void LOG(std::string_view text)
```

Be aware that you should use `string_view` only in places where it would make equal sense to use a reference type (so, parameters, and that's it).

Also be aware that when people see `LOG("foo")` in your code, they will assume that `LOG` is a macro, because it's ALL UPPER CASE. If you mean for people to assume it's a function, call it `print_to_log` or something like that.

Comment: I know you wrote it for effect, but *every constructor you ever write* is possibly a bit over-the-top!  It's probably a good starting point, of course, and it's a shame that couldn't have been the default, with authors specifying just those cases where implicit conversion should be allowed.

Comment: "_every constructor you ever write_ is possibly a bit over-the-top!" — I would actually bet (a small amount of) money that OP will never _need_ to write an implicit constructor in their life. Relatively few people ever implement `std::string(const char*)` or `BigNum(int)`, or even `Allocator<T>(const Allocator<U>&)`. We agree it's a good starting point at least. :)

Comment: Well, there's also `Size(std::size_t, std::size_t)` where adding `explicit` is noise at best - only constructors that can be called with a single argument actually *need* `explicit`.  I do agree that compromising readability is less bad than a surprising conversion, though.

Comment: I'd say in that case "adding `explicit` is noise _at worst_." In the average case, it's turning `new_matrix({x,y})` into a compiler error and forcing the caller to write out `new_matrix(Size(x,y))`, so it's more apparent to the reader which overload of `new_matrix` they should be looking for. In the best case https://godbolt.org/z/XgChsg (I have no idea what's happening here). Btw, I'll add `std::true_type()` to my list above — I admit I've used `std::true_type foo() { return {}; }` in preference to `auto foo() { return std::true_type{}; }` — but again OP won't implement `true_type` IRL.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question:

> To go with all unique pointers or should we use shared pointers in this case?

You're absolutely correct to return `std::unique_ptr` values.  This indicates that ownership of the pointed-to object is transferred to the caller.  If you were to return `std::shared_ptr`, then that would imply that the factory retained a share of the ownership (e.g. by retaining an object pool, or something).

Remember that once the caller has a unique pointer, it is able to convert it to a shared pointer if it needs to (but the opposite conversion is obviously not possible, except via the raw pointer).

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed a few small things:

- You don't need to flush the stream every time you log something. A simple newline will do.
- A more suitable log stream provided by C++ would be `std::clog`. You may, however, need to flush this stream.
- Your formatting is inconsistent. You have spaces in places where you don't have spaces elsewhere, including but not limited to: in template parameters and after `return`. This makes the code slightly hard to read.